How to export the content of a shiny tab containing HTML elements and CSS flexboxes in pdf format?
I've defined a shiny tab containing HTML elements and CSS styles. This tab is divided into 3 columns, each containing rectangles: all created with div(). When I launch the application, I get the visual I want. Now I want to add an export button below my visual to export the page content in PDF format.
I've tried to create an export button that passes through a Rmarkdown file and then saves the content in PDF format. However, nothing appears in the PDF. Here's the code for my ui: it consists of my code with html elements and css styles and the export button :
mod_ex1_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(

    shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
    shinybrowser::detect(),
     div(
             style = "flex: 1 0 25%; margin-bottom: 0px;",
             class = "rectangle-container", 
             # First part
             div(
               style = "background-color: #00ff00; padding: 0px; border: 1px solid black; display: flex; align-items: center;border-top-left-radius: 20px; border-top-right-radius: 20px;",  # Cadre noir
               tags$img(src = "www/image.png", width = "21%", style = "margin-right: 10px;"),
               div(style = "flex : 1;text-align: center; display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center; height: 100%;",
                   h3("Part", style = "margin-bottom: 0px;margin-top:0px")
               )
             ),
             # Second Part
             div(
               style = "background-color: #00ff00; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid black;",  # Cadre noir
               p("Name of the club"),
               h1(style = "font-weight: bold;", textOutput(ns("nom_club"))),
               HTML("<span style='font-size: 12px;'> Name of the club </span>")
             ), 
downloadButton(ns("dl_comparaison"), "Exporter", style="color: #white; background-color: #164194; border-color: #164194; font-size: 11px; line-height: 11px;")
)

This part of my tab's server code contains output in response to the button, which exports an Rmd file in html format and then transforms this html file into a pdf. (I've done a similar thing to export a kable table).
output$nom_club <- renderText({
      vals$club
    })

output$dl_club = downloadHandler(
      filename = function(){
        return("club.pdf")
      },
      content = function(file){
        rmarkdown::render(
          "R/club.Rmd",
          output_format = "html_document",
          output_file = "export.html",
          envir = parent.frame(),
          params = list(
            club = vals$club
          )
        )
        webshot::webshot("R/export.html", file)

      }
    )

I then transcribed the code into an rmd file as follows :
---
title: "Club"
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
  css: style.css
params:
  club: NULL

nom_club <- params$club

    

library(htmltools)
HTML('
           div(
             style = "flex: 1 0 25%; margin-bottom: 10px;",
             class = "rectangle-container",  # Classe pour appliquer le cadre noir
             # First part
             div(
               style = "background-color: #16adff; padding: 0px; border: 1px solid black; display: flex; align-items: center;border-top-left-radius: 20px; border-top-right-radius: 20px;",  # Cadre noir
               tags$img(src = "www/LCE-Inclusion.png", width = "21%", style = "margin-right: 10px;"),
               div(style = "flex : 1;text-align: center; display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: center; height: 100%;",
                   h3("Part", style = "margin-bottom: 0px;margin-top:0px")
               )
             ,
             # Second part
             div(
               style = "background-color: #16adff; padding: 10px; border: 1px solid black;",  # Cadre noir
               p("Name of the club"),
               h1(style = "font-weight: bold;",  nom_club )),
               HTML("<span style=\'font-size: 12px;\'> Name of the club</span>")
             )
      )
             
      </div>

     ')


If you spot an error or have any suggestions, thank you in advance.
